# Changing inline CSS with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to change this div tag's style when an image is clicked, and its not working. 
First I want to check and see if the style is "display:none;" or "display:block". But when I try to alert the value it returns "undefined" for both when the display is set to none and when it is set to block.

```
<div id="navbar-mobile-id" style="display:block;" class="navbar-mobile">
```

This is in my function: (function works when clicked but alerts "undefined")

```
alert(console.log(document.getElementById("navbar-mobile-id").style.display));
```

This should alert either "block" or "none"

Comment: `alert(console.log("hi"))` is also going to alert undefined. Why is an console inside the alert?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The return value of `console.log()` is `undefined`

If you want to alert the value of the `display` property, then you have to alert **that**.

```
alert(document.getElementById("navbar-mobile-id").style.display);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!